# Global objects via services in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

After entering my application my `GlobalApplicationController` initializes some services used through the whole application (like subscribing to sockets, etc.). It would be pretty handy to have a `CurrentUser` object - but I'm not sure about the object I get

```
@app.factory 'CurrentUser', ($http) ->
  user = $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'users/me'
  }).then (data) ->
    return data
```

The returned object contains a `$$state` object. To get to the actual data I need to call `CurrentUser.$$state.value.data`.

I want my service to be called like `CurrentUser.email` (or whatever attribute), but I have no idea what type this returned object is or why I'm getting it.

**Edit**: I've found out that the returned object I get is the `$http` object (due to coffeescript). Is there a way to return the data (*not* a promise)?

Answer (score 1):

From [$http General Usage then()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) docs:

> The response object has these properties:
>
> ```
> data – {string|Object} – The response body transformed with the transform functions.
> status – {number} – HTTP status code of the response.
> headers – {function([headerName])} – Header getter function.
> config – {Object} – The configuration object that was used to generate the request.
> statusText – {string} – HTTP status text of the response.
> ```

So you would want to change

```
return data
```

To

```
return data.data
```

Comment: I've found out that the returned object is actually the `$http` object (due to coffeescripts), not the returned value within the `then()`. Assigning the value of the returned data to a variable and return it isn't possible, since the promise isn't fulfilled at the time the function is called (at least I think so). I'm not too familiar with promises, but any ideas how to solve that?